# Code protection system which works with IronPython assemblies?

Tags: asp.net, ironpython

do you know/have you tried any code protection system which works with IronPython assemblies? Can you list it/them here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since iron python compiles to IL I would imagine you can use the same obfuscations tools such as DotFuscator.

Are you using the pyc tool included in iron pythons tool folder?

Comment: yes, why? 
:) :) (needed more characters to be able to post the commentary lol )